# Linq Dynamic OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

I read other post and comments in StackOverflow.com but couldn't understand the solution.

Here is the code:

```
var qry = (from m in db.Messages
                           join r in db.Recievers on m.Id equals r.Message_Id
                           let a = m.SendDate
                           let b = (m.DoneDate != null ? m.DoneDate : DateTime.MinValue)
                           let c = m.Comments.Max(c => c.CommentDate)
                           let d = (c != null ? c : DateTime.MinValue)
                           let e = (radDropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0 ? a : a >= b ? a >= d ? a : d : b >= d ? b : d)
                           orderby e descending
                           select m).Distinct();
```

**Notes:**

radDropDownList1 has two items. the 0 means the orderby must be based on SendDate of messages and 1 means the orderby must be based on the biggest value among SendDate, DoneDate and maximum date in comments. The above code does not return the result I expect. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As per my first look, the code to initiate `e` variable is wrongly written.

A proper `if ... then ... elseif` statement using conditional `?:` operator should look like:

```
var answer = condition ? first_expression : second_expression
```

See: [?: Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Let split it into multiple lines using standard notation:

```
if (radDropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
  a
else if (a >= b)
  if (a >= d) 
   a
  else
    d
else if (b >= d)
  b
else
  d
```

Note: i do not use `{}` brackets to leave code more readible.

In case when you use multiple `if... then ... elseif` statements, you have to excercise special caution!

Answer (score 0):

*The above code does not return the result I expect:* you conditional expression is the cause

I would suggest you to write in this way:

```
let e = radDropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0 ? a /*order by SendDate*/
                                                /*otherwise , order by MAX(a, b, c)*/
                                            : new DateTime(Math.Max(a.Ticks, Math.Max(b.Ticks, c.Ticks)))
```

---

**EDIT:**
*Yes, sorry, as you mentioned, the SQL will not know about DateTime Ticks*

Let's find the max in this way:

```
    var selectedIndex = radDropDownList1.SelectedIndex;

    var query =
        (from m in db.Messages
         join r in db.Recievers
           on m.Id equals r.Message_Id
         let a = m.SendDate

         let b = (m.DoneDate != null ? m.DoneDate : DateTime.MinValue)
         let c = m.Comments.Max(c => c.CommentDate)
         let d = (c != null ? c : DateTime.MinValue)

         let tempMax1 = a > b ? a : b
         let tempMax2 = tempMax1 > c ? tempMax1 : c

         let e = (
               selectedIndex == 0 ? a /*order by SendDate*/
                                  : tempMax2) /*otherwise , order by MAX(a, b, c)*/
         orderby e descending

         select m)
        .Distinct();
```

P.S. The elegance will be up to you ;)

Comment: I did what you said, but get the error says: The member 'System.DateTime.Ticks' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: I Just observed, you should use `d` instead of `c` in expression `let tempMax2 = tempMax1 > c ? tempMax1 : c` . So it would be `let tempMax2 = tempMax1 > d ? tempMax1 : d`

Comment: I did what you said again, but the result is not ordered as I want. Could you please test it with some data in your computer to see the wrong result?

Comment: post in question a set of data for test and the result you expect.